# uploadify flash version - clear queue from .net code

Tags: uploadify

I am trying to clear an uploadify queue from a .net method by this:

```
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascript:$('#" + file_upload_reply.ClientID + "').uploadifyCancel('*')", True)
```

but it does not clear the queue. Is it possible to clear the queue using the command uploadifyCancel?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Library ScriptManager:

> Manages ASP.NET AJAX script libraries and script files, partial-page
>   rendering, and client proxy class generation for Web and application
>   services.

Use ClientScript:

Such as in Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered("cancel"))
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "cancel", "javascript:$('#aa').uploadifyCancel('*')", true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but (I should have said) it is being called from an update panel and so the script is definitely being called. I wonder if my uploadify syntax is incorrect?

Comment: I just used the latest version,http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/cancel/

Comment: thanks but this doesn't do the job either - code:  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascript:$('#" + file_upload_reply.ClientID + "').uploadify('cancel')", True)